# How to properly define multiple env variables for all jobs on .travis.yml

Tags: travis-ci

The [documentation](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#Defining-Multiple-Variables-per-Item) says:

> When you define multiple variables per line in the env array (matrix variables), one build is triggered per item.

```yml
rvm:
  - 1.9.3
  - rbx
env:
  - FOO=foo BAR=bar
  - FOO=bar BAR=foo
```

But what if I define only 1 per line? I'm doing the following:

```yml
env: 
  - FOO=1
  - BAR=2
  - BAZ=3
```

But it's triggering 3 builds? I expected it to trigger 1 build, with those 3 env variables. Do I have to defined them like this?

```
env:
  - FOO=1 BAR=2 BAZ=3 QUX=4 ........ =10
```

Or am I missing something here?

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You need to define them as global variables:

```yml
env:
  global:
    - FOO=1
    - BAR=2
    - BAZ=3
```

See [Global variables](https://docs.travis-ci.com/user/environment-variables/#global-variables) documentation for more info.